# What if we change axiom of arithmetic?

Tags: arithmetic, axioms

I want to experiment with some ideas about changing the axioms of arithemetic. (You know, like changing axioms of Euclidian geometry, we get non-Euclidian geometry.)

What happens when we change the rules of addition ?

You know that :

- $\forall x\,\forall y\,(x + y = y + x)$
- $∀x\,∀y\,∃z\,(x+y=z)$

If we change that into :

- $x + y$ is not always equal to $y + x$ the same way as $x^y$ is not always equal to $y^x$
- $x + y = z$ only if $x \geq y$

Yes, it's pretty different. For example, you're sure that if $x + y = z$ then $z \leq 2x$.

Does this change a lot of things? Does it create new axioms?

Comment: Please use some quantifiers in this part: $$\text{ $x + y = z$ no matter what is $x$ or $y$}$$ I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I mean that when you add $x$ and $y$, there is always a result. This is not the case of the division. You can not 5 divide by 0.

Comment: We can actually prove that $x+y=y+x$ from the Peano axioms and some definitions of $+$, so it is not an axiom.

Comment: @Pyrofoux You should write $\forall x\forall y\exists z(x+y=z)$.

Comment: Please don't close this question. Sure, its worded a bit naively, and probably the OP doesn't know heaps about the foundations or about abstract algebra, but still its an interesting suggestion, and could lead into a discussion of say, the arithmetical hierarchy and different levels of soundness (from a foundational perspective) and ring and field theory (from an abstract algebra perspective). Plus, its very well-intentioned.

Comment: If $x+y\neq y+x$ then you cannot create a number system because $1+1$ lead us to define the next number $2$. If $1+1\neq 1+1$ then we cannot define $2$, so how to create natural numbers. I think that the arithmatic what you think cannot have a number system.

Comment: @GitGud is there any difference between quantifiers "for all" and "no matter what"? ;)

Comment: I understand the votes to close, but I think that if we can get this OP to narrow the scope, it will be a good question.

Comment: @Mathlover I didn't say $1+1 ≠ 1+1$  I say that $x + y$ is not sur and certain equal to $y + x$ :)

Comment: @WORLDDOMINATION Maybe not, but that's natural language and therefore, naturally, subject to interpretation.

Comment: More close votes, after it was closed an reopened? We might need to make a few more tweaks to placate them.

Comment: Hi @Pyrofoux : I made some edits to the body of the question to trim up how you phrased things. I really wanted to do the question justice, but if I somehow messed what you meant up, just let me know and I'll undo whatever parts you don't like. Regards.

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you very much, I don't know what to say to thank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first idea (arithmetics in which addition isn't [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property)) has definitely been studied. In abstract algebra, a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29) is an object that has two operations we usually call "addition and multiplication." In those, the addition operation is always required to be commutative.

But there's a name for the same thing without the requirement that $+$ be commutative: they're called [near-rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearring).

---

The second idea you had is a bit more unusual, since it restricts what things can be added. Usually if you're defining an arithmetic, you want $+$ to be defined everywhere. Nevertheless, people have still studied algebraic objects with *partially defined operations*.

Division in the real numbers is (barely) partially defined since division by zero isn't permissible. I know, though, there are far stranger (more partially?) defined operations out there.

---

Actually upon rereading the way you stated the second case, there's a pretty obvious example of an operation with those properties: division on the (positive) natural numbers. There exists $c$ such that $a/b=c$ only if $a\geq b$. This operation also is not commutative!

I would have used division in the integers, but then I'd had to have changed to $|a|\geq|b|$.

Unfortunately, I don't think it makes a good candidate to be an addition operation for an arithmetic: I'm not sure what kinds of multiplication would distribute over it.

Comment: Note also that non-commutative addition is a staple of ordinal arithmetic (with the Cantorian operations).

Comment: @user18921 Also another good example :) [Here's a link for that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic) if you are interested, Pyrofoux.